# Load Hive out put from pig

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, apache-pig

I am new to `Hive`, i was using `Pig` for loading data from `Cassandra`, since i am facing some problem with loading data from `Cassandra` (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6151) while filter for partition key.

So planning to use Hive to load data from `Cassandra` and processes it through `Pig`. Is it possible to read the `Hive` out put data by `Pig` Script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is. But Hive can produce a lot of various kinds of outputs. Please, be more precise in your question.

Comment: Am planning to do this load data from cassandra by creating external tale. query this table and store data on hdfs like this INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output/dir' SELECT * FROM cassTab. Is this possible to do.?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [HCatalog](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HCatalog/CURRENT/loadstore.html). It will look like this in Pig:

```
cassTab=LOAD 'CassTableName' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 
DUMP cassTab;
```

You may find more details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+UsingHCat) and [here](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-use-hcatalog-basic-pig-hive-commands/) (it's for HUE but will help anyway).

Comment: 'CassTableName' is the Cassandra table name or external table name that is created in Hive for cassandra or is it the output directory of the Hive.

Comment: Let's say it's a name of a Hive table in HCatalog. HCatalog allows you to see Hive tables from Pig.